# Android studio project cannot compile after adding facebook api

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I try to use facebook api in an android studio project, and I strictly follow the official facebook api tutorial. However, after making all the changes my project cannot compile anymore. Is there anything wrong with the setting?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oapmq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II6y7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple build.gradle files in a project the one you have placed the facebook dependency is the top level project file which is wrong. Any libraries you want to include should be inside the build.gradle file which is inside the "app" folder of a barbones Android Studio project and will already include a dependencies node which you only need to add the facebook dependency below.